# Display hours in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, events, date, fullcalendar

I'm trying to show hours for my events in FullCalendar, I have something like this :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: [
        {
            title:  'Event',
            start:   '2010-01-01 14:30:00',
            allDay: false
        }
    ],
    timeFormat: 'H(:mm)'
});
```

It works : it displays hours inside the event(s) but I would like to see all hours at the left like [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) (select week or day).

Is there any way to get that ?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: It would more clear if you make a fiddle in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I'm beginner, I'm sorry I did not get what you meant.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/](http://jsfiddle.net/) is an online code editor, you can post your code save it and then copy the url post it here.  so that others can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need are the agendaWeek and agendaDay views (see [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/)). These are set in the [header](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/header/) like so (you can add/omit/move buttons as appropriate):

```
header: { left: 'prev,next title today month,agendaWeek', right: '' }
```

Comment: What you need is [slotMinutes](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/agenda/slotMinutes/)